# What does an Oyster £5 One Day Bus and Tram Pass look like?

Tags: tickets, london, buses, tfl

If anyone has used an [Oyster £5 One Day Bus and Tram Pass](https://www.tfl.gov.uk/campaign/new-fares-for-2015?intcmp=23318#on-this-page-8), which has been recently introduced in January 2015, could you please post a picture of it here? Is it still available for purchase, or is it dead already? It's a tough claim but, (clearing throat), it seems that there's no picture of this bus pass on the entire Internet! A picture of this card might be useful to know for fellow travelers who want to see London by bus.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Isn't it this one (taken from [this site](http://www.travellikealocal.org/en/uk/london-guide/getting-around-london-tube-bus-and-oyster-card/)):

[image: bus tram pass]
<sub>(source: [travellikealocal.org](http://www.travellikealocal.org/en/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2013/06/daily-bus.jpg))</sub>